# How to capture screen exits on Android with Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, manual

I'm using Google Analytics V2 for Android.  I chose to use the manual method of logging screens so that I could log screens from within Fragments.

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance().sendView( "/home" );
```

However, when I look at the results, the Avg Screen Time is way too high.  I did a number of tests where I went to a screen then left the phone idle for many minutes.  I'm not sure how Google determined a screen visit had ended it was definitely minutes after the phone display dimmed.

So the question, is there a way to tell Google Analytics the screen view is over?  It seems EasyTracker has this concept, but the manual method does not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is use to you, but what I do is send a view when app pass to background:

```
myTracker.sendView("onBackground");
```

And for screen where I wanna know the time what I do is calculate it manualy:

```
Date initial;

onCreate(...)
    initial= new Date();

onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
   long time= ((new Date()).getTime() - initial.getTime());
   myTracker.sendTiming("Time", time, "name", "label");
}
```

If you want you can calculate time in onPause and onResume to subtract time onBackground.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into using onPause and onResume, but those get fired _alot_ when the phone display times out.  I'm trying some other approaches now - I'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: I was thinking that onPause onResume only calculate time but you send time only one time in onDestroy.

Comment: I ended up doing basically what @k0nig did.  I tried to use EasyTracker but those methods were very unreliable in the Real-Time activity tracking so difficult for QA to verify.  Instead I used only sendView and created a fake background screen that I called in onStop() for activities or fragments.